# In L'Hopital's 1st theorem - do we need this requirement that $f$ and $g$ are continuos at the point $a$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

See please "THEOREM 1 (l'Hopital's Rule for zero over zero)" here:

[L'Hopital's 1st theorem - source 1](https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/%7Ekouba/CalcOneDIRECTORY/lhopitaldirectory/LHopital.html)

**I wonder if there we need also the requirement that $f$ and $g$ are continuous at the point $a$ or not**.

Or... does that follow from the other conditions of the theorem? If so, how does it follow?

The Wikipedia page also does not put that requirement.

[L'Hopital's 1st theorem - source 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule)

I have a textbook which requires that $f$ and $g$ are continuous at the point $a$ when it states L'Hopital's 1st theorem. And in fact this continuity at $a$ is used significantly in the proof presented in the textbook (which uses btw Cauchy's generalized mean value theorem).

On the other hand... I just don't see how the values of $f$ or $g$ at $a$ should influence the conclusion from the theorem.

So I wonder where the ultimate truth lies.

I think maybe in the textbook they required this condition just to simplify some technicalities in the proof which would otherwise be slightly more involved.

E.g. if $f(a) \ne 0$ we can always define another function $f_1$ which is the same as $f$ except in the point $a$ where $f_1(a) = 0$
Same for $g$. And then we can use $f_1$ and $g_1$ in the proof, these will be indeed continuous at the point $a$ but their limits will be the same as the limits of $f$ and $g$ so the rest of the proof will work just fine.

Is that the idea... to avoid this technicality?

Comment: Yes it is just a technicality. Your theorem is about limits so the value at the point should not play any role. You can always extend by continuity and apply the standard theorems.

Comment: @GReyes So there's no need to require that $f$ and $g$ are continuous at the point $a$, correct?

Comment: That is right. Just the limits at $a$ should be zero. The functions may not be even defined there.

Comment: @GReyes Right, thanks very much for the confirmation. This absolutely matches my line of thought.